# The following packages have unmet dependencies: can't install any software. Ubuntu 16:04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have unmet dependencies when trying to install gitlab, VLC, GParted and other packages.

```
openssh-server :   
 Depends: openssh-client (= 1:7.2p2-4)  
 Depends: openssh-sftp-server but it is not going to be installed  
 Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
```

for VLC:

```
vlc :  
  Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed  
  or libgles1 Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed  
  or libgles2
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I've even tried:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install openssh-server -y
```

I have tried basically everything, but nothing is working. I can't even install gitlab or any other application.

Comment: Quick question, what dependencies are being shown as unmet? What software sources do you currently have enabled?

Comment: We'd be happy to help, Timothy, but it seems that it lacks of information here. In which context did you get that message of unmet dependencies? What are you trying to do?

Comment: here are some: For gitlab
`openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:7.2p2-4)
                  Depends: openssh-sftp-server but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed`

for VLC:
`vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or  libgles1
       Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or libgles2`

to mention but a few

Comment: @avazula
i was trying to install **gitlab, vlc, Gparted** and others

Comment: I hope that is a typo, but the command should be `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @Terrance yes. sorry it was a typo

Comment: Are you getting any errors during the `sudo apt update`?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1026444/edit) your question and add these details into it and not down here in the comments.  Best if you copy and paste the errors that you are seeing.  We need details so that we can help you better.

Comment: @Terrance. No there are no errors on update

Comment: These problems are usually caused by something the user did, like adding a PPA or other repository. Did you or someone else do something like that?

Comment: @Zanna
well, I think there is a time something like that happened. I'm not a geek like most of you, so I guess it might have happened.

Comment: Hi @TimothyMach  You need to update (read: **EDIT**) your question with output from the commands you are running.  Pasting small snips in the comment field isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking at some of the packages that you are having issues with for it to install.  When I did an `apt search` it was showing `xenial-updates` for the application:

```
~$ apt search libgles1-mesa
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libglapi-mesa/xenial-updates,now 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
```

It sounds to me that you might not have the correct repositories enabled.

Go to *Settings -> Software & Updates*.

Check the Ubuntu Software tab and make sure that they all are enabled:

[image]

Then go to the Updates tab and make sure that they are enabled too:

[image]

Then click Close at the bottom and I believe that it will want to update the repositories and check for updates.  Then try your installations again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hope this helps OP. I assumed they have a a package conflict & we need more info to see where it is. I'll check back later!

Comment: @Terrance
Thank you so so so much. Works like charm. I'm grateful.

Comment: @TimothyMach You are welcome!  Glad I could help!  =)