# My Ubuntu Software doesn't show installed programs or available programs any more

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, software-center

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

My Ubuntu Software doesn't show installed programs or available programs any more. the **All** tab doesn't show available programs since my last update.

My Software Updater shows 90Mb of updates to be downloaded but the technical description and the details of the updates are invisible
I have tried running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

and

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

but there is no change.

When opening Ubuntu Software Center (not Ubuntu Software), it shows Software Center was not removed.

From the terminal while removing software center:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing software-center,
 directory '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/piston'
 not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing software-center,
 directory '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro'
 not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing software-center,
 directory '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db'
 not empty so not removed
```

Right after removing Software Center with the terminal, the program is still available (Ubuntu Software) and keeps doing the same but now the icon of the Ubuntu Software Center is missing.

Comment: I've had the same issue since the kernel upgrade last week. The Software Center has always been buggy and has never been fixed properly. I've decided to delete it permanently. You can always see what's installed from `xdg-open /usr/share/applications`.

Comment: Please see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051107/why-is-ubuntu-software-center-dropping-previously-provided-applications  There are bugs filed against the Ubuntu Software not showing applications any more.  Removing and reinstalling does not fix it.  It is something Canonical has to address, or it could be further upstream with the GNOME Software developers.  The original Ubuntu Software does work still, but it is not fully updated.  I posted that in my answer.

Comment: any advice on the 'software updater', how to reinstal  or repair it?

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk` should reinstall the software updater.

Comment: Ubuntu Software is something different.  You would need to reinstall the GNOME Software Center to get it back.  `sudo apt install gnome-software gnome-software-common`

Comment: runningsudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk

Comment: @Terrance, running [sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk] get this message: Reinstallation of software-properties-gtk is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.

Comment: Did you disable the xenial-updates repo by accident?

Comment: @Terrance, sudo apt install gnome-software gnome-software-common, removed ubuntu software, but did not reinstall it. am I missing something?

Comment: I think you need to check your repositories.  Beyond this, I am out of suggestions and would recommend a full reinstallation as I don't know what you removed.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1026589/231142 for repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a known bug which Canonical must fix, may I offer an alternative until then?  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-install-synaptic.html.en describes the Synaptic Package Manager which is described in the link above as *more powerful and can do some software management tasks which Ubuntu Software can't*.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix some problems with:

```
pkill gnome-software
sudo rm -r /var/cache/app-info
sudo appstreamcli refresh --force --verbose
```

These lines solved my problems :-)

Found the above commands in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051118/527764) to [Why is Ubuntu Software Center dropping previously provided applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051107/why-is-ubuntu-software-center-dropping-previously-provided-applications) by [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance).

Comment: This cleared up my problem with the Software app being out of touch with reality.