# How can I get the 'Make' command in Ubuntu with USB?

Tags: command-line, usb, make

I want to start this off by mentioning that I am very new to using Linux, so I'm having a pretty hard time figuring this one out on my own.

Version: Ubuntu Desktop 18.04

I went out and bought a wireless card for this PC so that I can connect to my home internet, however the card will not just "Plug-and-Play." I did some searching online and came across some drivers as well as instructions for installing them via USB, but I seem to have run into an issue. The instructions state that I need to use commands such as "make",  Running the make command in the terminal returns the following:

```
Command 'make' not found, but it can be installed with:
.
sudo apt install make
sudo apt install make-guile
```

and running sudo apt install make returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
this may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate
```

I can imagine I'd get this error for all other commands I try to run.

If it helps at all, I'm trying to follow instructions found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver) to install these drivers. I then did some searching online trying to find a way to get the 'make' command, but pretty much everything says that I will have to connect the machine in question to the internet. I'm looking for a way to either get the make command (and other commands that I will need for installing drivers) onto this PC, or a way to install drivers without using these commands.

Anything I put onto the machine will be coming from a Windows laptop to the Ubuntu machine via a flash drive. Again, I want to say, it is not possible for me to use an Ethernet connection at this time. Thanks in advance for any help you all provide :)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: `make` and `build-essential` are in the `main` repository.  Please see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1026589/231142 and make sure that the Ubuntu Software repositories are enabled so you can install them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried that, it returned several failures (all say `W: Failed to fetch http://*`)
I'd guess this has something to do with not having an internet connection. Kind of a Catch-22 huh? Do I absolutely *need* an internet connection to get `make`?

Comment: Yes you do need an internet connection to get make as it is probably not downloaded by default to your system.

Comment: ahh. So I can't download these to my USB flash drive and transfer them over to the machine in question then? Just making sure that I fully understand what's being said.

Comment: Look into something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: If you have access to another Ubuntu system on the internet at the same version you can always download them on that system, copy it over to your USB then install on the local system.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469489/2012250 because that will help get all the dependencies needed for each package.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own another Ubuntu system with internet access, but I will look in to the second link you posted and try to go from there. If I do find a way to get an ethernet connection, do I just need to put `sudo apt install build-essential` and `sudo apt install make` in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, with the ethernet connection that is what you would type in.  You can actually combine them into one line like `sudo apt install build-essential make` and you can keep adding on as need be for whatever is needed.   On the windows system you could also look into installing VirtualBox and putting a copy of Ubuntu in there so you can download into that then copy to the USB from there.  Just trying to think of things that could help you!

Comment: When I said "I don't own another Ubuntu system" I totally forgot about VirtualBox! Thanks so much for reminding me. :) May be what I need to get this all done. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @NathanCarrell btw, [`build-essential` depends on `make`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/build-essential), so you only need `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. Use `apt-get` instead `apt` - `apt` tries to be friendly and deletes the downloaded deb files after installation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to get this working. Writing this on my new Ubuntu workstation now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options from using an offline repository/package manager to burning a set of DVD/USB images with the packages you need.  Regardless of the approach, either you will need access to an Internet connected machine or find someone who can do this for you to actually get the packages you need and any dependencies (there will be quite a few for the development tools.)  See [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) for more information on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the tools needed to build that driver by using:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

This will install `make` and a C++ compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
This returns essentially the same thing as running `sudo apt install make.`
I'd assume this is because I am not connected to the internet?